# COUNT and MAX applied to LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

Given the tables and relationships in the image below:

[customer table & offices table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTHVv.png)

I would like to answer the following question:

- Which is the city with the largest office (most number of employees)?

To solve this answer, I tried this query:

```
SELECT counts.city, counts.numEmployees 
FROM (
    SELECT o.city, COUNT(e.lastName) AS numEmployees
    FROM offices o
    LEFT JOIN employees e
    ON o.officeCode = e.officeCode
    GROUP BY o.city
    HAVING numEmployees = MAX(numEmployees)) AS counts;
```

This results in an empty set. However, this query worked:

```
SELECT counts.city, counts.numEmployees 
FROM (
    SELECT o.city, COUNT(e.lastName) AS numEmployees
    FROM offices o
    LEFT JOIN employees e
    ON o.officeCode = e.officeCode
    GROUP BY o.city
    HAVING numEmployees = 6 ) AS counts;
```

I am trying to undestand why MAX() does not return the expected value and what is evaluating. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need rows with employee count for each city/office combination, and then you also need to get the maximum of those counts, these are 2 steps but you initially tried to achieve both together and that does not work.

Using a CTE helps here (if this is available to you depending on MySQL version) because the CTE can be referenced in a subquery used within the where clause for the overall maximum.

Alternatively (again if version allows it) you can use the `over()` clause which will calculate the maximum on the grouped rows which is done AFTER the group by, so it is useable in a subsequent where clause.

> ```
> with counts as (
>     SELECT o.city, COUNT(e.lastName) AS numEmployees
>     FROM offices o
>     LEFT JOIN employees e
>     ON o.officeCode = e.officeCode
>     GROUP BY o.city)
> select *
> from counts
> ```
>
> ```
> city | numEmployees
> :--- | -----------:
> A    |            3
> B    |            2
> C    |            2
> ```

> ```
> with counts as (
>     SELECT o.city, COUNT(e.lastName) AS numEmployees
>     FROM offices o
>     LEFT JOIN employees e
>     ON o.officeCode = e.officeCode
>     GROUP BY o.city)
> select *
> from counts
> where numEmployees = (select max(numEmployees) from counts)
> ```
>
> ```
> city | numEmployees
> :--- | -----------:
> A    |            3
> ```

> ```
> select city, numEmployees, maxof
> from (
>     SELECT o.city, COUNT(e.lastName) AS numEmployees
>     , max(COUNT(e.lastName)) over() as maxof
>     FROM offices o
>     LEFT JOIN employees e
>     ON o.officeCode = e.officeCode
>     GROUP BY o.city
>     ) d
> ```

> ```
> city | numEmployees | maxof
> :--- | -----------: | ----:
> A    |            3 |     3
> B    |            2 |     3
> C    |            2 |     3
> ```

> ```
> select city, numEmployees
> from (
>     SELECT o.city, COUNT(e.lastName) AS numEmployees
>     , max(COUNT(e.lastName)) over() as maxof
>     FROM offices o
>     LEFT JOIN employees e
>     ON o.officeCode = e.officeCode
>     GROUP BY o.city
>     ) d
> where numEmployees = maxof
> ```
>
> ```
> city | numEmployees
> :--- | -----------:
> A    |            3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f30c6159b7a2305c4181e38a36b10156&hide=3)*

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest aggregates in the same query. Since `numEmployees` is a `COUNT()` aggregate, you can't use `MAX(numEmployees)` in the same query.

Do this in the outer query.

```
SELECT counts.city, counts.numEmployees 
FROM (
    SELECT o.city, COUNT(e.lastName) AS numEmployees
    FROM offices o
    LEFT JOIN employees e
    ON o.officeCode = e.officeCode
    GROUP BY o.city) AS counts
HAVING numEmployees = MAX(numEmployees);
```

Comment: Actually, I tried that but it raised an error because counts.city is not the column used inside the MAX().